LINQ query involving AutoMapper and options from automapper
The problem i am encountering is that : I have a Resolver to get me the price for the current dimension on my current product. But , in my Resolver i am passing in the context.Items dictionary i am passing a key-value-pair like this : "Product" : productObj. I need to pass that to get the price for the current dimension. This resolver is used in my automapper , which maps from the Dimensiuni to the DimensiuniDto. I am writing a query to get the products listed into ProductsListingForUsers dto from the Produse table. The error i am encountering is that the line opt => opt.Items["Product"].Add(product) cannot be translated to SQL, but i really need to use that automapper to get the price per dimension.
This is my query:
public async Task<IList<ProductsListingForUsers>> GetProductsForUsers(int? pageNumber)
    {
        var productsRepository = _unitOfWork.Repository<Produse>();

        var upcomingProducts = productsRepository
            .GetSimpleQueryable();

        var takePaginatedProducts = await upcomingProducts
            .Skip(pageNumber ?? 0 * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize)
            .Select(product => new ProductsListingForUsers
            {
                CodProdusDto = product.CodProdus,
                NumeProdusDto = product.NumeProdus!,
                TipulProdusuluiDto = product.TipulProdusului,
                PretBazaDto = product.PretDeBaza,
                PretBazaRedusDto = product.PretDeBazaRedus,
                DimensiuniProduseDto = product.PProduseCuDimensiuni!
                    .Select(dimensiune => _mapper.Map<DimensiuniDto>(dimensiune.PdDimensiune , 
                        opt => opt.Items.Add("Product" , product))
                    ).ToList(),
                CuloriProdusDto = product.PProduseCuCulori!
                    .Select(culori => new CuloriDto
                    {
                        NumeCuloareDto = culori.Culoare.NumeCuloare,
                        CodCuloareDto = culori.Culoare.CodCuloare.CodCuloare!,
                        JustAdded = false,
                        ImaginiProdusDto = culori.ImagProduseCuCulori!
                            .Select(image =>  new ImagesDto
                            {
                                CaleImagineDto = image.CaleImagine!,
                                FisierInBucketDto = image.FisierInBucket,
                                PresignedUrl = null,
                                JustAdded = false,
                                IdProdusCuCuloareDto = 0
                            }).ToList()
                    })
                    .ToList()
            }).ToListAsync();


        foreach (var product in takePaginatedProducts)
        {
            foreach (var color in product.CuloriProdusDto)
            {
                if (color.ImaginiProdusDto.IsNullOrEmpty()) continue;
                foreach (var image in color.ImaginiProdusDto!)
                {
                    image.PresignedUrl = await _bucketAcces.GenerateUrl(image.CaleImagineDto, image.FisierInBucketDto);
                }

            }
        }


        return takePaginatedProducts;
    }

This is the resolver
using AutoMapper;
using E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.DTO.ProduseDtos.ProductOptionsDto;
using E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.ProductRelatedModels;
using E_Commerce_BackEnd.UnitOfWork;

namespace E_Commerce_BackEnd.Services.Helpers.Resolvers;

public class DimensionPriceResolver : IValueResolver<Dimensiuni, DimensiuniDto, decimal>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public DimensionPriceResolver(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public decimal Resolve(Dimensiuni source, DimensiuniDto destination, decimal destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dimensionOnProductRepository = _unitOfWork.Repository<ProduseCuDimensiuni>();
        

        if (context.Items["Product"] is not Produse product)
        {
            // Handle case when the product is not available
            return 0;
        }

        // Find the price for the dimension and product combination
        var findPriceForTheDimension = dimensionOnProductRepository
            .FindQueryable(pd => pd.IdDimensiune == source.IdDimensiune && pd.IdProdus == product.IdProdus)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        

        // Return the price if found, or default to 0
        return findPriceForTheDimension?.Pret ?? 0;
    }
}


This is the mapper
 CreateMap<Dimensiuni, DimensiuniDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RecomandarePat, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RecomandarePat))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LungimeDto, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Lungime))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LatimeDto, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Latime))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PretDto, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom<DimensionPriceResolver>())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PretRedusDto, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom<DiscountDimensionPriceResolver>());

This is the join table between Produse and Dimensiuni
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.ProductRelatedModels;

public class ProduseCuDimensiuni
{
    
    public int IdProdusCuDimensiune { get; init; }
    
    // Foreign Keys
    public decimal Pret { get; set; }
    public decimal PretRedus { get; set; }
    public int? IdDimensiune { get; set; }
    public Dimensiuni? PdDimensiune { get; set; } 
    public int IdProdus { get; set; }
    public  Produse  PdProduse { get; set; } = null!;
    
    
}

The ProductsListingForUser dto :
using E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.DTO.ProduseDtos.ProductOptionsDto;

namespace E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.DTO.ProduseDtos.ProductsListingForUsers;

public class ProductsListingForUsers
{
    public string CodProdusDto { get; init; } = null!;
    public string NumeProdusDto { get; init; } = null!;
    public string TipulProdusuluiDto { get; init; } = null!;
    public decimal PretBazaDto { get; init; } 
    public decimal PretBazaRedusDto { get; init; } 
    public IList<DimensiuniDto>? DimensiuniProduseDto { get; init; } = [];
    public IList<CuloriDto> CuloriProdusDto { get; init; } = [];
}

The Dimensiuni table


using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.OrderRelatedModels;

namespace E_Commerce_BackEnd.Models.ProductRelatedModels;

public class Dimensiuni 
{
    
    public int IdDimensiune { get; init; }

    [StringLength(4)] 
    public string Lungime { get; init; } = null!;
    
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string Latime { get; init; } = null!;

    public bool? PerdeaEstePereche { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string? RecomandarePat { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProduseCuDimensiuni>? DProduseCuDimensiuni { get; }
    public ICollection<AsociereSeturi>? DAsociereSeturi { get; }
    public ICollection<ProduseCuComenzi>? DProduseCuComenzi { get; }

    public Dimensiuni()
    {
        
    }

    public Dimensiuni(string lungime, string latime,string? recomandarePat ,ICollection<ProduseCuDimensiuni>? dProduseCuDimensiuni)
    {
        Lungime = lungime;
        Latime = latime;
        RecomandarePat = recomandarePat;
        DProduseCuDimensiuni = dProduseCuDimensiuni == null ? [] : new HashSet<ProduseCuDimensiuni>(dProduseCuDimensiuni);
    }
    
}

One way would be to iterate again after and do the mapping. I really do not want that. Is there another way ? Please if i forgot to put something , leave a comment and i will update the post.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization
